# Parse the Markdown-like Markup!

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

## The Challenge

In this challenge, you are supposed to write a program or function that takes in a String, which will contain the simplified Markdown-like Markup, and outputs the corresponding HTML Markup.

---

## The Input

You can take input in whatever way you wish to. The `type` of the input should be String.

---

## The Output

You can output the result in any way you want. Logging to Console or Terminal, printing on screen, returning from function etc. are perfectly valid.

---

## The Rules

- Convert each occurrence of `*foo*` and `_foo_` to `<em>foo</em>`.
- Convert each occurrence of `**foo**` and `__foo__` to `<strong>foo</strong>`.
- Convert each occurrence of `<tab or four spaces here>foo\n` to `<pre><code>foo</code></pre>`.
- Convert each occurrence of `#foo\n` to `<h1>foo</h1>`.
- Convert each occurrence of `##bar\n` to `<h2>bar</h2>`.
- Convert each occurrence of `###bar\n` to `<h3>bar</h3>`.
- Convert each occurrence of `####bar\n` to `<h4>bar</h4>`.
- Convert each occurrence of `#####bar\n` to `<h5>bar</h5>`.
- Convert each occurrence of `######bar\n` to `<h6>bar</h6>`.
- Convert each occurrence of `[foo](https:\\www.bar.com)` to `<a href="https:\\www.bar.com">foo</a>`.
- Convert each occurrence of `![foo](https:\\www.bar.com)` to `<img src="https:\\www.bar.com" alt="foo"/>`.
- Convert each occurrence of `>foo\n` to `<blockquote>foo</blockquote>`.
- Convert each occurrence of `- foo\n` as `<li>foo</li>` (add `<ul>` before the `li` if the `-` is the first of its consecutive series and add `</ul>` if it is the last.)
- Convert each occurrence of `n. foo\n` (where the first `n` denotes an Integer such as 12,1729 etc.) as `<li>foo</li>` (add `<ol>` before the `li` if the element is the first of its consecutive series and add `</ol>` if it is the last.)
- Although there exist many more rules of conversion, you are supposed to follow only the abovementioned ones (for the sake of simplicity).
- You are supposed to output only the corresponding HTML Markup for the given String. No need to add extra elements that are necessary for creating a valid HTML file (like `<body>`, `<html>` etc.). However, if they are present in the input String, then you will have to output them too, that is, replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, repspectively.
- *You must NOT use any built-in! (I doubt whether there exists one)*

**Note :** In the abovementioned rules, `foo`, `bar` and `https:\\www.bar.com` are only placeholders. Your program or function must be flexible enough to work for Strings different than these too.

---

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

---

## Test Cases

```
"**Hello**" -> "<strong>Hello</strong>"

"#IsThisAwesome?\n" -> "<h1>IsThisAwesome?</h1>"

">![Image](http:\\www.somewhereontheinternet.com) -> "<blockquote><img src='https:\\www.somewhereontheintenet.com' alt='Image'/></blockquote>"

">Some Content\n- Item1\n- Item2\n- Item3\n" -> "<blockquote>Some Content</blockquote><ul><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li><li>Item3</li></ul>"

"1.Hello\n2.Bye\n3.OK\n" -> "<ol><li>Hello</li><li>Bye</li><li>OK</li></ol>"
```

---

## Special Thanks to [FakeRainBrigand](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3402/fakerainbrigand)!

This challenge was originally proposed by [@FakeRainBrigand](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3402/fakerainbrigand) in the Sandbox. He granted me the [permission](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/656#656) to post this challenge on the regular website. Due to unclear and broad specifications, the challenge was closed. Now, it has been reopened with clearer and fewer specs by [@Arjun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45105/arjun).

Comment: Good point. I removed that from the post.

Comment: It would be nice to have a more rigorous specification for each rule.  For instance I notice that your ordered list input are not numbers 1-3 while the result is.  It would be nice to know exactly what is required.

Comment: I didn't write this challenge but thanks for the feedback

Comment: I vote to close as unclear what you're asking because there are at least 500 unexplained corner cases. Markdown is an incredibly tricky language that everyone has some idea of what it 'should look like', but a formal specification is quite long. This is nowhere near a complete specification.

Comment: @orlp If you read the title and the question it is a basic markdown parser. I also give the inputs I will feed.

Comment: What is the valid order of convertion in case of nested similar marks? `*foo *bar* foo*` would be converted to `<em>foo </em>bar<em> foo</em>` and not to `<em>foo <em>bar</em> foo</em>` ?

Comment: @Dead the first one.

Comment: ***R E T I N A.***

Comment: What about escapes? ` \1. ` should produce ` 1. ` in normal markdown, but does that apply here?

Comment: @programmer5000 uhh hmm. Sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## PHP, 770 Bytes

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4202b268bfa43041300a426637cf9f51d90e4443)

There are some rules to make html with this markup

the replacement of blockquote must before all others

h6,h5,h4,h3,h2,h1 is the next order

strong, em

img, a

and (li ,ul, li,ol) or (li ,ol, li,ul)

```
$s=[
"%>(.*)\n%Us"
,'%(\*|_)\1(.+)\1\1%Us'
,'%(\*|_)(.*)\1%Us'
,'%######(.*)\n%Us'
,'%#####(.*)\n%Us'
,'%####(.*)\n%Us'
,'%###(.*)\n%Us'
,'%##(.*)\n%Us'
,'%#(.*)\n%Us'
,'%- (.*)\n%Us'
,'%(?<!</li>)<li>%Us'
,'%</li>(?!<li>)%Us'
,'%\d+\. (.*)\n%Us'
,'%(?<!li>|ul>)<li>%Us'
,'%</li>(?!<(li|/ul)>)%Us'
,'%(\t|    )(.*)\n%Us'
,'%!\[(.*)\]\((.*)\)%Us'
,'%\[(.*)\]\((.*)\)%Us'
];
$r=[
'<blockquote>\1</blockquote>'
,'<strong>\2</strong>'
,'<em>\2</em>'
,'<h6>\1</h6>'
,'<h5>\1</h5>'
,'<h4>\1</h5>'
,'<h3>\1</h5>'
,'<h2>\1</h5>'
,'<h1>\1</h5>'
,'<li>\1</li>'
,'<ul><li>'
,'</li></ul>'
,'<li>\1</li>'
,'<ol><li>'
,'</li></ol>'
,'<pre><code>\2</code></pre>'
,'<img src="\2" alt="\1"/>'
,'<a href="\2">\1</a>'
];
echo preg_replace($s,$r,$i);
```

Comment: Good job! Testing right now

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 641 bytes

```lua
t={"<","&lt","^.+(>)","&gt","^(#+)(.*)",function(a,b)return("<h%d>%s</h%d>"):format(#a,b,#a)end,"^>(.*)","<blockquote>%1</blockquote>","^[\t ]+(.*)","<pre><code>%1</code>","!%[(.-)%]%((.-)%)",'<img src="%2" alt="%1"/>',"%[(.-)%]%((.-)%)",'<a href="%2">%1</a>',"%*%*","","__","","%b","<strong>%1</strong>","","","%b**","<em>%1</em>","%*","","%b__","<em>%1</em>","_",""}for l in io.lines()do u,U=l:match("^- ")or u and print("</ul>"),u o,O=l:match("^%d%. ")or o and print("</ol>"),o for i=1,#t,2 do l=l:gsub(t[i],t[i+1])end print((l:gsub("^- (.*)",(U and""or"<ul>").."<li>%1</li>"):gsub("^%d%. (.*)",(O and""or"<ol>").."<li>%1</li>")))end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJNb6MwEL314F8xMfLWJsQo2VvkIDXdj/bUy/aUTREBAqgGZ8GcVvvbs2OHKq1UCXu@3ntjxtZjdj7bzV@qaES/aIv7i5zzRLiw8iEP5oLLEDPHscttYzqeRQfRl3bsO05VzYqEDSp2lor10fRtZnmAmCjIRNkVqJFcBKg6aJO//hmNLRO2VPG70LXa/bawn79hT32ZqNwUF6h3MD1jOy4Xgu0Z9xaht6ppKxj6fEPZikKmLTpLGie3Ef0MnUHdl0cP9tKZB4YsRPkbXGk6Oexw44wabG@6ymMndwJ4TOh4qmx9HY1Lhm9Fr/Wx6DL0H84JNDQdNEbqpisHLgoDY/S80WscYF5z@rIAKhA2QtYVcOqbzuK841HjnKMRTPT0DssKJi9w8xFuPNyAa9hsllFgoxVgK43kahgP3O6afYTbfLl31zUx@VR1p7jcCH92wpSanip/Bimp0o3/MzR49xPBH2XiPF055jOOcC3P5yB4KLU2M0J@1c0A@GWAU3ldw652hT2vrT0N6zg@GiNz0wry2GZVuYbZDjPXsiO5eoxPQp66SpDkquhfGlnAHa4trnuylHC3vScrCd@@/yBfJfx8eCRhuDW6CENIU@ekKQnL9lRj7ExK/gM)

#### Readable Version and Explanation

```lua
t = { -- Table used for simple replacements
    "<", "&lt",
    "^.+(>)", "&gt", -- Cannot be at the beginning of a line because of blockquotes
    "^(#+)(.*)", function(a,b)return("<h%d>%s</h%d>"):format(#a,b,#a)end, -- Combined h# replacement
    "^>(.*)", "<blockquote>%1</blockquote>",
    "^[\t ]+(.*)", "<pre><code>%1</code>",
    "!%[(.-)%]%((.-)%)", '<img src="%2" alt="%1"/>',
    "%[(.-)%]%((.-)%)", '<a href="%2">%1</a>',
    "%*%*", "", -- Using the actual control character is shorter than using an escape code
    "__", "",
    "%b", "<strong>%1</strong>",
    "", "",
    "%b**", "<em>%1</em>",
    "%*", "",
    "%b__", "<em>%1</em>",
    "_", ""
}

for l in io.lines() do -- For every line in STDIN
    u,U=l:match("^- ") or u and print("</ul>"),u -- Some compact logic to print the end of the lists and mark things as such
    o,O=l:match("^%d%. ") or o and print("</ol>"),o

    for i=1,#t,2 do
        l=l:gsub(t[i],t[i+1]) -- Run through the table of replacements
    end

    print(( -- Use two parentheses so that we only print the first return value
        l:gsub("^- (.*)", (U and "" or "<ul>") .. "<li>%1</li>") -- Rest of the list logic
        :gsub("^%d%. (.*)", (O and "" or "<ol>") .. "<li>%1</li>")
    ))
end
```

I can expand upon specific things if wanted, but it's very late as-of posting this so it'll have to wait until later.